# Cant use TabBar delegate methods

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I got an app with my custom TabBar Controller Class.

I tried to implement tabbar controller delegate method:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSLog(@"%i",tabBarController.selectedIndex);
}
```

But it doesnt work. Why?

in `ViewDidLoad` i write:

```
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
```

And in .h i implement:

```
@interface BaseViewController : UITabBarController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>
```

Comment: Did you actually set the tab bar controller's delegate?

Comment: And you set up your class to implement the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` in your .h?

Comment: yes. i write <UITabBarControllerDelegate>

Comment: @MiQUEL that was more than year ago. i think, yes ))

Answer (score 3):

In your custom TabBarController, do not use

```
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
```

But use

```
self.delegate = self;
```

.tabBarController returns the nearest ancestor in the view controller hierarchy that is a tab bar controller, but your custom TabBarController IS the controller you want to target, so no need to search in its hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

You have said, that it's your custom TabBarController. What is the customisation you've done? If you changed the TabBar panel and replaced it with your own to use

```
setSelectedIndex:
setSelectedViewController:
```

methods manually, then you should call delegate's methods manually too.

According to the [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH3-SW20):

> There are two types of user-initiated changes that can occur on a tab
> bar:
>
> - The user can select a tab.
> - The user can rearrange the tabs.
>
> Both types
> of changes are reported to the tab bar controller’s delegate, which is
> an object that conforms to the UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol.

Also check the [UITabBarControllerDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006932-CH3-SW1)

> In iOS v3.0 and later, the tab bar controller calls this method regardless of whether the > selected view controller changed. In addition, it is called only in response to user taps in > the tab bar and is not called when your code changes the tab bar contents programmatically.

Delegate will respond only if **user** interacts with its UITabBar control.